# sails lift very slow exceeds 15 seconds

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I have a macbook with SATA disk. I have mysql running in my local machine. My npm test tried to lift sails and then run some unit tests on it. It takes more than 15 seconds and I have to

```
this.timeout(15000);
```

in bootstrap.test.js where it lifts my sails server. I have my colleague pulling same code and able to run

```
npm test
```

in less than 2 seconds. Is there any mistake on my laptop like installing mysql in wrong directory. Is there any way I can improve speed of my server.